# Best practices for adding comments to Symfony project

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am working on a project that allows a user to add articles. I would like users to be able to add comments to each article. I'm trying to create a system for doing this but I don't think my implementation is efficient. So far I have comments controller with the CRUD in place but it's not integrating cleanly with my articles controller. Basically I'm looking for some pointers on how to go about doing this in a more elegant way.

Comment: Maybe you want this? https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle

Answer (score 1):

Symfony is too broad solution to give advices on such specific topic.

There is bundle that can simplify managing threaded comments
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

But the best code is no code. May be you can manage comments outside your application:

- https://disqus.com/ (you can download comments to serve them via PHP, not JS if you need it for SEO - https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpDisqusBundle )
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/